# Call Back Lambda Expressions + JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

So, I am trying to renew one of my old JavaFX applications which were created upon Java 6 Release. I was given a tip that I could convert this current code and use lambda expressions instead, could someone help me convert this piece of code here or somehow guide me?

```
// define a simple boolean cell value for the action column so that the column will only be shown for non-empty rows.
    addColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<UserDetails, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
        @Override public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<UserDetails, Boolean> features) {
            return new SimpleBooleanProperty(features.getValue() != null);
        }
    });

    // create a cell value factory with an add button for each row in the table.
    addColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<UserDetails, Boolean>, TableCell<UserDetails, Boolean>>() {
        @Override public TableCell<UserDetails, Boolean> call(TableColumn<UserDetails, Boolean> personBooleanTableColumn) {
            return new AddPersonCell(window, tableUser);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @DVarga, you may do without the innermost curly braces and the `return` keyword: `addColumn.setCellValueFactory(features -> new SimpleBooleanProperty(features.getValue() != null));`.

Comment: All of guys are really really good at programming, I wish to become the same! :)

Comment: Continue practising and continue asking questions as good as this one, and you will be. I’m only learning lambdas too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lambda expressions only work, if there is a single abstract method in the interfact. Since this is the case for `Callback` this can be one here.

Basically you place the anonymus class with a lambda expression of the form `(<parameters>) -> <method body>`.

In this case

```
new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<UserDetails, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
    @Override public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<UserDetails, Boolean> features) {
        return new SimpleBooleanProperty(features.getValue() != null);
    }
}
```

becomes

```
(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<UserDetails, Boolean> features) -> {
    return new SimpleBooleanProperty(features.getValue() != null);
}
```

This could be further simplified:

1. If the parameter types are not needed to decide the method to be called, they can be removed.
2. If there is only a single parameter without a type, the `()` brackets can be removed.
3. If the method body contains only a single statement, the `{}` and the `;` can be removed. If the statement is a `return` statement, the `return` keyword needs to be removed too.

This allows you to further simplify the lambda expression to

```
features -> new SimpleBooleanProperty(features.getValue() != null)
```

---

Using the same approach

```
new Callback<TableColumn<UserDetails, Boolean>, TableCell<UserDetails, Boolean>>() {
    @Override public TableCell<UserDetails, Boolean> call(TableColumn<UserDetails, Boolean> personBooleanTableColumn) {
        return new AddPersonCell(window, tableUser);
    }
}
```

can be changed to

```
personBooleanTableColumn -> new AddPersonCell(window, tableUser)
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what you can do is replace every private class implementing an interface/abstract class with a single abstract method (one that implements the so called `@Functional` interface) with a lambda expression. Java will know that the lambda corresponds to the sole method that was to be overridden. So, for every case of:

```
SomeFunctionalClass foo = new SomeFunctionalClass() {
    @Override
    public ReturnType someMethod(Type1 someParam, Type2 someOtherParam) {
         <code goes here>
    }
}
```

you replace it with:

```
SomeFunctionalClass foo = (someParam, someOtherParam) -> { <code goes here> };
```