# Why does the lambda equivalent of a CheckBoxTableCell's setSelectedStateCallback fail to compile in JavaFX8?

Tags: javafx, lambda, callback, javafx-8

A relative Java newbie question.

I was trying to fix a different issue I have with a `CheckBoxTableCell` and came across this post:  [CheckBoxTableCell changelistener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210690/checkboxtablecell-changelistener-not-working).

While experimenting with user James_D's example, I tried to turn a `setSelectedStateCallback` into a lambda expression.  However, it didn't compile and generated an "incompatible parameter types in lambda expression" error.

The original code looks like this:

```
cbCell.setSelectedStateCallback(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer index) {
        return selected;
    }
});
```

NetBeans 8.2 converted it to this:

```
cbCell.setSelectedStateCallback((Integer index) -> selected);
```

I then followed user fabian's answer in this post [Call Back Lambda Expressions + JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143888/call-back-lambda-expressions-javafx) to manually write the lambda and ended up with the same thing.

Why doesn't the lambda expression compile?  How should it be written such that it does compile?

If it helps, here is a MVCE with the original and lambda-equivalent code.

I'm using JavaFX8 (JDK1.8.0_181).

```
package test26;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Test26 extends Application {

    private Parent createContent() {

        TableView<TestModel> table = new TableView<>();
        ObservableList<TestModel> olTestModel = FXCollections.observableArrayList(testmodel -> new Observable[] {
                testmodel.checkboxProperty()
        });
        olTestModel.add(new TestModel(false));
        table.setItems(olTestModel);

        TableColumn<TestModel, Boolean> colCheckbox = new TableColumn<>("checkbox");

        colCheckbox.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().checkboxProperty());

        colCheckbox.setCellFactory((TableColumn<TestModel, Boolean> cb) -> {

            final CheckBoxTableCell cbCell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
            final BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

            //Original code ...
            cbCell.setSelectedStateCallback(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer index) {
                    return selected;
                }
            });

            //... and lambda equivalent that doesn't compile
            cbCell.setSelectedStateCallback((Integer index) -> selected);

            return cbCell;
        });

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.getColumns().add(colCheckbox);
        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(table);

        return content;

    }

    public class TestModel {

        private BooleanProperty checkbox;
        public TestModel() {
            this(false);
        }
        public TestModel(
            boolean checkbox
        ) {
            this.checkbox = new SimpleBooleanProperty(checkbox);
        }
        public Boolean getCheckbox() {
            return checkbox.get();
        }
        public void setCheckbox(boolean checkbox) {
            this.checkbox.set(checkbox);
        }
        public BooleanProperty checkboxProperty() {
            return checkbox;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using raw types in this declaration, hence it expects `Object` not an `Integer`. But you are explicitly passing an `Integer` here that leads to the error.

```
final CheckBoxTableCell cbCell
```

A quick and dirty fix would be

```
cbCell.setSelectedStateCallback(index -> selected);
```

In the above case the compiler will infer the type as `Object` since it is not given explicitly. But this will give you an unchecked warning. So in long run use generic types instead of raw types.

Parameterize your declaration of the `CheckBoxTableCell` like below and it will fix all the unchecked warnings in your code. So this will be a life saver.

```
final CheckBoxTableCell<TestModel, Boolean> cbCell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
```

And then change your code back to the initial incarnation which you used like so,

```
cbCell.setSelectedStateCallback((Integer index) -> selected);
```

Notice that now there's no any compilation error. Then delete the type `Integer` and let the compiler to infer it.

Comment: Thank you, Ravindra.  Your explanation has also given me a clue re what to look for if/when I encounter the "incompatible parameter types" error again.

Comment: You are welcome ! Fix all the unchecked warnings in your code.

Comment: I have updated my answer, change the code as directed above.